# supporting multiple screen including Kiosk

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, androiddesignsupport

I know this has been asked many times, And I understand the difference between Dp,Sp etc

Also I know the qualifiers that should be used with the resources. But Right now I am working with a App that should work equally and same on all devices. I have designed it for tablet and it looks good.

**What I want**

- I want my layout specifically run on Kiosk , for this What qualifier should I use with the Layout folder ?
- Also I want to support Tablets , if I will use the layout-xlarge , i have observed it will run on both the 10 inch Tablet and the kiosk , whereas I want to run different design on both differently (tablets 10 inch and kiosk)
- What qualifier specifically describe each category , let say I want layout buckets for mobile , tablets 7 inch , tablets 10 inch , kiosk ?? what should I do for this ?

> How can I do this ? there is no such information about kiosk on the android developer site.? Please help...

Comment: did you got the answer

Comment: no still working on ......